# Laravel: How to add signature option to migrate:rollback command?

Tags: laravel, migration, command, rollback

I have multiple databases and the migrations for each database are stored in a different folder. Hence, I want to override the `migrate:rollback` command and add an option for a folder instead of specifying the path every time.

*So instead of running the following command:*

`php artisan migrate:rollback  --path=/database/migrations/{{folder}}`

*I want to run:*

`php artisan migrate:rollback {{folder}}`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $signature = 'test {folder}';

protected $description = 'Testing Purpose';

public function handle()
{
    $this->ask('Enter Folder Name?');
    
    $folder = $this->argument('folder');

    $command = "migrate:rollback --path=/database/migrations/{$folder}";

    Artisan::call($command);
}
```

Comment: This does not work as I want the signature to be migrate:rollback {folder} but migrate:rollback does not have options in its signature